# How to apply a function that returns a dataframe to groupby objects

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, apply

The function I want to apply to each groupby object is the [ATR](https://www.quantopian.com/posts/talib-dot-atr) function, it takes in three ndarrays and returns a dataframe object. And I also want to put the result in a new column of the original dataframe.
Here is the code that i wrote:

```
# the original dataframe:
 col1    col2    col3    group
4762.1  4762.9  4762.9     1
4762.3  4762.1  4762.9     2
4762.3  4762.9  4762.1     1
4762.7  4762.5  4762.5     2
4762.5  4762.5  4762.5     1
  ...     ...     ...     ...

def get_atr(df):
    return ta.ATR(df['col1'].values, df['col2'].values, df['col3'].values)

df['atr'] = df.groupby('group').apply(get_atr)
```

The expected outcome should be

```
 col1    col2    col3    group       atr
4762.1  4762.9  4762.9     1    (the result)
4762.3  4762.1  4762.9     2    (the result)
4762.3  4762.9  4762.1     1    (the result)
4762.7  4762.5  4762.5     2    (the result)
4762.5  4762.5  4762.5     1    (the result)
  ...     ...     ...
```

But I get all NaN values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try create new column in function:

```
def get_atr(x):
    x['atr'] = ta.ATR(x['col1'].values, x['col2'].values, x['col3'].values)
    return x

df = df.groupby('group').apply(get_atr)
```

Comment: the last line might should be ```df = df.groupby('group').apply(get_atr)```.